# Zariski topology of $k^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I've found this "proof left to the reader" in some lecture notes:

> Let $k$ be an arbitrary field. In the Zariski-Topology of $k^2$ every closed set of $k^2$ is either finite or the zero set of a *single* polynomial.
>
> This follows from the fact that two coprime polynomials in $k[X,Y]$ share at most a finite number of zero points.

I was not able to prove this. Can you give me a hint? I'm also a little baffled because this would mean that say the union of the $x$-axis and a single point is again the zero set of a single polynomial.

In $\mathbb{R}$ we could still write a point $(x,y) = Z((X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2)$ as the zero set of a single polynomial, but this makes use of the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ has an ordering.

Comment: You are perfectly right to be baffled and your counter-example is perfect.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: The OP's example is not covered by the linked question. It seems that the OP's book should have said "irreducible" closed set.

Comment: Who wrote these lecture notes?

Comment: I'd rather not say. But I'm going to talk to the author in a few days and update here.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in those notes is only true for irreducible ideals. As your counterexample shows, it is not true in general. One such counterexample would be the ideal generated by $xy$ and $x^2-x$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. The zero set is not finite and the ideal is not generated by one polynomial.